# laravel include in layout app is taking too long to load page

Tags: laravel, include, sidebar, yield, laravel-10

I am making a project on laravel 10. When i include sidebar file in my layouts.app file then page takes too long to reloa and it never opens page and i have to restart my server.
[layouts.app file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlaUw.png)

But when i include sidebar in my index file which extends layouts.app file then it works fine.
[Index.blade.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd70X.png)

What could be the reason?

i also tried to yield sidebar in layouts.app file but then again page starts loading and never stops reloading.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76891119/edit) your question and put up code as text in a code block, as code is text, images have to be downloaded, are horrible for accessibility and search, and do not allow anyone to copy your code and try it